# Cascading dropdowns based on a php query

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a dropdown which contains each day of the week.

```
DAYS[Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday]
```

I then run this query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT DAY_1 FROM credit_three"
```

and I put the results in another drop-down, using the following code:

```
<select name='DAY_1' onchange="ILovePHP();">
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo"<option value='" .$row['DAY_1']."'>". $row['DAY_1']."</option>";
    }
</select>
```

When the value in the dropdown changes, I need to run another query. To do so, I have tried the following:

1. On-Change I am running the function `ILovePHP()`, which is provided by the script:

   b=
       alert(b);

myfunction() was written in php like

```
function myfunction() {
    $sql = "SELECT TIME_1 FROM CREDIT_THREE WHERE DAY_1=DAY1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql2);
    row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 }
```

But... my query isn't running. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please change the title. It's confusing. It should be meaningful.

Comment: thanks for replay ..and i changed the title

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo - you are putting your query into a variable called `$sql` but then passing a different variable to `mysql_query`, "`$sql2`"

```
$sql="SELECT TIME_1 FROM CREDIT_THREE WHERE DAY_1=DAY1";
$result=mysql_query($sql2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to run the server-side function.

Try this:

```
<script>
function myfunction(str2) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.php?q=" + str2, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

To set the value of `str2`, you need to pass in `this.value`

In the `ajax_info.php` page, you can now code your query and the result will be shown to you in the `div` tag with `id="mydiv"`. You can do this anywhere in your front-end page, as follows:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Now you can use the line:

```
echo"<option value='" .$row['DAY_1']."'>". $row['DAY_1']."</option>";
```

in your `ajax_info.php` page, and get the result you want in the `div` tag.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: thanks for your replay,,,,and what i need to write in ajax_info.php file and how send the values from ajax_info.php to my php page.

Comment: you need to write your query in that page and print the result there only..you nothing to send from that page,it will automatically come under mydiv tag

Answer (score -1):

You need to send ajax request on change of dropdown and this ajax request will get the result from query and create html and then you need to replace html with jquery.
For detail you can see the following link..

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list-demo.php